# Display taxonomy terms from a vocabulary as columns in a Views table

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type called Resource with two taxonomy fields: States (Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, etc.) and Type of Resource (Handbook, Standards, Training).

So a piece of content would have the following: 
Content Title
State: Arizona 
Type of Resource: Handbook

I am trying to create a table of data in Views that would display taxonomy terms across the top of the table as headers and then I'll use views aggregation to pull the number for each as such:

```
|States    |Handbook    |Standards    Training  
|Alaska    |            |2            |1
|Arizona   |1           |             |
```

I am able to get a total count of resources for each state:

```
|States    |Total Resources   
|Alaska    |3          
|Arizona   |1
```

But have been unable to figure out how to get taxonomy terms into my field as column headers, any ideas?

Uses Views 7.3.

Comment: How two occurrences of `Standards`  happened to `Alaska`? you mean the content with `Alaska` value as States and `Standards` as type of resource has been added twice?

Comment: There can be multiple Resource nodes, each node has taxonomy terms of States and Type of Resources associated with it. So there could be two resources added tagged with both Alaska and Standards.

Comment: Brother, this could be done using a few lines of code, if you are happy with a non-views answer, let me know.

Comment: My preference would be to do this through views, but I would be interested  in doing it through code as well. Could you point me in the right direction @Alexar